# Can't run terminal command: ionic which gives error [zsh: command not found: ionic] right after installing [npm install -g @ionic/cli] with no issues

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, path, zsh, apple-m1

I recently got a mac mini with an m1 chip and tried to install my environment. So far I've managed to install node/npm and Homebrew correctly and the commands work. The **problem** begins when I try to **install Ionic globally**. In reference to this documentation, https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli, I proceed to enter the command:

`npm install -g @ionic/cli`

The installation process works. Immediately after I run:

`ionic start`

And then I get this error: **zsh: command not found: ionic** I think it has to do something with my paths, but I can't seem to figure it out.  [Here is the error I'm referring to on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTauC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So continuing from the first response, my search ended up in [node version manager](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). Here I managed to install nvm and switch between node versions. I used this video as reference [how to install and use nvm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohBFbA0O6hs).

I installed ionic again `npm install @ionic/cli` and it works!

The only issue I encountered is when I close out my terminal and reopen it again, **nvm** points to my **system version of node** and ionic doesn't work anymore. It begins working again once I use **nvm** and switch to the most recent version of **node**.

Here is an image when ionic [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQEgU.png) and when [it does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyVEp.png).

UPDATE: Managed to fix the issue at the end. I ended up making **nvm** switch to the most recent version of **node** and also made it the **default setting**. I also went ahead and removed the **system version of node**.